# SQL*Plus query: table joins with aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE users
()

CREATE TABLE avatars
()

CREATE TABLE weapons
()
```

I need two queries for these tables that I created and I am having trouble doing it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. For all Avatars produce a list showing the avatar name, the total number of weapons it currently holds and the total cost of all weapons currently held. I want no more extra information shown apart from these three main pieces, so I need to get information from table 2 and 3.
2. For any given User email (i.e. entered at runtime) list the owned Avatar names in reverse order of date of birth and the weapons (including weapon name, range and cost) held by that Avatar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using SQL*Plus. The tables are not very efficient so any improvements would be welcomed but mainly I need help with these queries.

Comment: Did you try to write something ?

Comment: so i don't get what you mean, if you mean did i attempt them yes i have, but i can only get either all the info from both tables or one table. im very new to this.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should share what you tried and why it doesn't work. Otherwise it looks like you're requesting people to write code for you, which is frowned upon around here.

Comment: select * 
from avatars
where user_id in ( select id from users where active = 1 and email like 'E%') i would use something like this, but this list all the columns from two tables. not sure how to only get specifics

Comment: Just replace `*` with the desired columns names. Pretty basic SQL stuff.

Comment: thanks that was simple, but how do i order stuff

Comment: You really need to start reading SQL tutorials. You won't progress by going blindly asking around such basic stuff.

Comment: I placed the query provided by op into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    max(a.name),
    count(1),
    sum(w.cost)
from
    avatars a
    inner join weapons w on w.weapon_id=a.no_wp_id
group by
    a.no_wp_id
;
```

---

```
select
    a.name,
    w.weapon_name,
    w.range,
    w.cost
from
    users u
    inner join avatars a on a.user_id=u.id
    inner join weapons w on w.weapon_id=a.no_wp_id
where
    u.email='given@email.com'
order by
    a.dateOfBirth desc
;
```

---

- If your queries depend on `email` being unique, you should have a unique key on it.
- Your `weapons` table does not appear to have a `range` column on it, but you implied it does in your requirement for query #2. I've included `w.range` anyway.
- In `avatars`, `no_wp_id` should probably be named something like `avatar_id` or just `id`, and in `weapons`, `weapon_id` should be named `avatar_id`.
- You should go through an SQL tutorial. Here's one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-overview.htm.

Comment: i get invalid identifier on 'w'.'fk_wp'. but i can see what you are trying to do. however any idea why this error might persist. (on the first query)

Comment: Oops, used `fk_wp` instead of `weapon_id`. Fixed it, let me know if it works.

Comment: got a new error, line 2 - not a GROUP BY expression.

Comment: Ah yes, that kind of error has always annoyed me; DBMSs should be smart enough to know that `a.name` is unique for each group of `a.no_wp_id`. Requires a trick to fix, I like to use `max()`. Fixed it, try it again.